# Why does React Native Webview not load image from a URL

Tags: android, css, react-native, react-native-webview

I have a website that loads images from the internet, I thought I could easily make a React App that just shows the webpage as a Web View

The Web Page loads up perfectly fine, and I added a log that shows that it does load the image URL's correctly.

**But the Images don't show on the Android app. I don't know how to debug React Native Apps Properly**

On the Web Page the image are shown through a CSS property 'background-image: url(image url)'
And I update that property, maybe that's is the source of the issue

This is the Web Site, it's made for mobile devices really and is still a WIP

https://praw.herokuapp.com/

**What I have tried:**
I used Android Studio to debug the APK and LogCat shows 1 error everytime I try change the Image

`E/StudioTransport: JVMTI error: 103(JVMTI_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT)`

Doing some searching online JVMTI_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT is an error that is caused because "The supplied memory buffer is too small."

```
That makes me think, React allocated memory for my app, but once I loaded a new image it didn't have enough memory to display it? What do you think?
```

That is all the info I could find on the error... Android Studio did not give me any other helpful info

Is this a bug maybe with React Native WebView? Should I raise a GitHub Issue?

Is there any other info I could share that may help?

**My Entire React Native Code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://praw.herokuapp.com/' }}/>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, turns out http requests are a no no... I probably shouldn't do what I did, but I changed the image URLs from http to https...

You need secure URLs otherwise the image won't show up

The errors in LogCat are useless and had nothing to do with the error. I guessed this was the issue by reading the Java source code on Web Views. Going through that gave me some hints and it worked... yay I guess

Comment: I have same issue my data come from API and this API give me URL some URL is sort and some URL is long long URL is working on a web view in react native but sort URL is not working in a web view in reigniting So what I can do

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the View

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <WebView style = {{flex:1}} source={{ uri: 'https://praw.herokuapp.com/'}}  />
    </View>
```

or try to add `<application android:largeHeap="true">` in android manifest

Comment: sorry, thank you so much, I tried that but still no luck. Android Studio LogCat shows a new error as well ```E/ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix```

Comment: I'm going to try start on a fresh React N project and see if that helps, I think I might have messed with a config file possibly

Comment: create the project didnt help sadly, still have no image and that new error

Comment: What is your webview version?

Comment: the latest version surly, but the problem is solved now, I think there's an option/setting for the web view I need to toggle to allow http requests, but I don't know what that is